# spring dependency injection in any java bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have application that look like below

### without spring (prior)

UI-> service --> **javabean**

p.s: my ui call service (not using DI) and i want to remain this way

> new service()

I want my **javabean** to do DI for certain bean from applicationcontext.xml file.
Should i use Applicationcontext.getBean(the ..xml) file in javabean or is there any better way to do it ***without changing the service layer*** and only modify the **javabean in bold**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at [@Configurable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Configurable.html) annotation ([Tutorial](http://www.olivergierke.de/wordpress/2009/05/using-springs-configurable-in-three-easy-steps/)).

The basic idea is that you add this annotation to your bean class. It will then inject any properties as soon as you create a new instance:

```
@Configurable
public class Person {
    private IPeopleDAO _dao;

    // SNIP

    public save() {
        _dao.save(this);
    }
}

// use it like this
new Person("john", "doe").save();
```

Comment: With the very large caveat that it uses load-time weaving, which only works in some classloader environments.

Comment: alternatively can use compile time weaving, but i havent found way to do it on netbeans without maven.